# Which is best PDR parser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, pdf-parsing

I want to parse the tabular information from a `.pdf` file,and want to display that tabular information in a `datagridview` in C#. What choices do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

For a free well supported alternative try [ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose has a comprehensive PDF parser, but I've been waiting a long time to have a couple of bugs fixed.